# 80amp or 100amp alternator, which is better?

Tags: toyota

The battery light came on while I was going to work and the car began to loose power to everything as I pulled into the parking lot at work. I plan to buy a new alternator install on my 02 toyota camry 2.4L.
Looking for a car alternator replacement,there is a 80 amp and a 100 amp available. Which one should I choose ? The higher amperage alternator,the better ? Is there any place where I have to be careful when buy an alternator ?
Please advice.

Comment: Unless there is a short or an aftermarket device which requires additional power, the 80 amp alternator is more than sufficient.

Comment: @the_storyteller fitting a larger alternator is **not** the solution to a short...

Comment: @SolarMike Correct, but it is a solution to an increased draw. ;)

Comment: @the_storyteller I agree for a bigger sound system or  extra lights but suggesting it is the solution to a short is not correct.

Comment: @SolarMike, I didn't say it was a solution if there was a short. I said that if there _wan't_ a short (or an increased draw), an 80 amp alternator was more than sufficient. The converse was not stated or intended. Nowhere did I _suggest_ that an 80, 100, or other amp alternator would solve either an increased draw or a short. So yeah... you're right of course.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would say if you can determine the amp rating of the one you are replacing then I'd replace it with the same amp rating, that amp rating has worked with your car for 17 years so ought to be good enough. You also know it should fit exactly, an uprated one may take more space than would fit in a cramped engine compartment.

However, if there's enough space under the hood a 100 amp unit costs almost exactly the same, so if it were me I'd put the 100 in provided it's not a squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

The 100A would be an upgrade over OEM.  Unless you're super into automotive audio and have turned your car into a boom car with a lot of amplifiers, 80A should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I heard high amp alternator will rob more power from the motor. I don't want to risk,so just bought a 80amp alternator replacement online from [Hex Auto Parts](https://www.hexautoparts.com/auto-engines-performance/alternators/) last week. It has been working fine for some days and provides enough power to run my 05 toyota rav4 and accessories.

Comment: Any alternator will only take the power from the engine that it needs to deliver to the battery & electrical systems (plus losses), this is what the regulator does so that the battery is not overcharged.